# Setting default value for spinner with custom adapter at position 0

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have seen lost of posts about this subject here but none of them helped me in my situation. 
I have array of shop cart items which have: name,nubmer,apartment number.
and I have the adapter to receive this array and populate the spinner.

This is the adapter:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<ShopCartModel> list;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ShopCartModel> list) {
        this.context = c;
        this.list = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(c));
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, null);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ShopCartModel tmp = list.get(position);
        name.setText(tmp.getName());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is my main:

```
 public class ShopCartScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        Spinner spin;
        ArrayList<ShopCartModel> shopCarts;
        SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter;
        GetShopLists getShopList;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.shop_carts_list);
         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            cartItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.newListItem);
            spin = new Spinner(ShopCartScreen.this);
            db = DBHelper.getInstance(this);
            int apartmentNumber = preferences.getInt("apartmentNumber", 0);
            apartment = new ApartmentModel(apartmentNumber);
        getShopList = new GetShopLists(this, shopCarts, spin, spinnerAdapter);
            getShopList.execute("link to the query");
        toolbar.addView(spin, 0);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            preferences = getSharedPreferences("appData", 0);
            boolean flag = preferences.getBoolean("ItemsLoadedFromDb", false);
            ShopCartModel tmp = shopCarts.get(position);
        getShopingCartList = new GetShopingCartList(this, list, adapter, cartItems, tmp.getNumber());
            getShopingCartList.execute("link to the query");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem and using some answer from this site I have created an [adapter](https://gist.github.com/nichtemna/65970fbddeaa9e8a8211c13351da7e03) that allows you to add default value for a spinner.

So for your situation you need create object of ShopCartModel with name that you want to use as default value and then use this adapter:

```
 ShopCartModel defaultModel = new ShopCartModel("Please choose cart model");

public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShopCartModel> {
public static final int HINT_COUNT = 1;
public static final int HINT_POSITION = 0;

public Adapter(Context context, int resource, List<ShopCartModel> valuesList, ShopCartModel defaultValue) {
    super(context, resource);
    List<ShopCartModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(0, defaultValue);
    list.addAll(valuesList);
    addAll(list);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView view;
    if (position == 0) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        textView.setHeight(0);
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view = textView;
    } else {
        view = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
    }
    parent.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, null);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ShopCartModel tmp = getItem(position);
    name.setText(tmp.getName());
    return convertView;
}}
```

Comment: But remember that items count is now bigger: list.size() + HINT_COUNT